# Pandas return row based on nearest value of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, is there a way to find a row that has a nearest value of 2 columns? I am not trying to find 2 separate rows, but the row that has the a value that in nearest for both columns. My data is as follows:

```
     Site  DTP  Capacity   WTG  AVAIL   OpEx
11    0.8   40      2000  18.0  0.966  46268
23    0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
35    0.8  100      2000  18.0  0.964  50904
11    0.8   40      2000  18.0  0.966  46268
11    0.8   40      2000  18.0  0.966  46268
11    0.8   40      2000  18.0  0.966  46268
59    0.8  200      2000  18.0  0.979  60734
71    1.2   40      2000  18.0  0.965  49000
107   1.2  150      2000  18.0  0.975  60279
107   1.2  150      2000  18.0  0.975  60279
83    1.2   60      2000  18.0  0.963  49580
23    0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
155   1.6  100      2000  18.0  0.965  59660
47    0.8  150      2000  18.0  0.979  60290
35    0.8  100      2000  18.0  0.964  50904
167   1.6  150      2000  18.0  0.965  59993
11    0.8   40      2000  18.0  0.966  46268
203   2.0   60      2000  18.0  0.951  58726
35    0.8  100      2000  18.0  0.964  50904
239   2.0  200      2000  18.0  0.951  59836
59    0.8  200      2000  18.0  0.979  60734
23    0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
227   2.0  150      2000  18.0  0.951  59392
59    0.8  200      2000  18.0  0.979  60734
299   2.4  200      2000  18.0  0.923  58739
```

I want to return the row that is nearest Site == 0.79 & DTP == 59. Or row 23, in this example. If I was looking for Site == 0.79 & DTP == 39, then it would return row 11.

I have tried this:

```
df_closest = subdf.iloc[(subdf['Site']-.79).abs().argsort()[:1] & (subdf['DTP']-59).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify how the distance should be computed. What if you have two exact matches but only on one column? How do you discriminate?

Comment: I will only have 1 match. The values to search for will be from user input.

If looking for Site == 0.79 & DTP == 59, then row 23 will be returned.

If looking for Site == 0.79 & DTP == 39, then row 11 will be returned.

Comment: Imagine the last row would have a site value of 0.9. What should be the chosen row for a `Site = 0.9, DTP = 100` query?

Comment: Sorry, lost the formatting on my table... this table shown is a subset. I guess I am looking for all the rows closest to my site input and then a subset of all the rows that match the second query.  I can do it in 2 lines with an additional df, but was hoping to simplify.

Comment: I see. I restored  previous version of your question with a reproducible dataset

Comment: Just to clarify: "*then a subset of all the rows that match the second query*" so you can have multiple rows in the output in case of equality?

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform a successive search.

- first get the group closest to the target
- then get the row with the closest DTP:

```
Site = 1.6
DTP = 40

group = df['Site'].unique()

idx = df.loc[df['Site'].eq(group[np.argmin(abs(group-Site))]),
             'DTP'].sub(DTP).abs().idxmin()
```

Output:

```
155
```

Intermediate:

```
group[np.argmin(abs(group-Site))]
# 1.6
```

##### keeping the closest site and all closest DTP:

```
Site = 0.79
DTP = 61
group = df['Site'].unique()

diff = df.loc[df['Site'].eq(group[np.argmin(abs(group-Site))]),
              'DTP'].sub(DTP).abs()
keep = diff.eq(diff.min())

out = df.loc[keep[keep].index]
```

Output:

```
    Site  DTP  Capacity   WTG  AVAIL   OpEx
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
23   0.8   60      2000  18.0  0.964  46939
```